# Using file_get_contents to get og:image meta data throws "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden" with some websites

Tags: php, file-get-contents, meta

I'm trying to use php to get meta data like og:image, title or description.

I'm using that code:

```
<?php
$sites_html = file_get_contents($url);

$html = new DOMDocument();
@$html->loadHTML($sites_html);
$meta_og_img = null;
//Get all meta tags and loop through them.
foreach($html->getElementsByTagName('meta') as $meta) {
    //If the property attribute of the meta tag is og:image
    if($meta->getAttribute('property')=='og:image'){
        //Assign the value from content attribute to $meta_og_img
        $meta_og_img = $meta->getAttribute('content');
    }
}
echo $meta_og_img;
?>
```

When I use this url (https://www.elmundo.es/papel/2019/01/28/5c4ed8effc6c83d2718b4605.html) it works perfectly but when I use this one (https://andresmartin.org/2016/09/mindfulness-la-fibromialgia-mirar-dolor-amabilidad-alivia-malestar-reduce-dolor/), I get the error.

How can I avoid this error? And if it is impossible to do, how can I get the meta data with another method?

I think it is not important but I'm using laravel.

EDIT: Here is a screenshot of the error https://pasteboard.co/HYPI7KV.png

Comment: Those sites might simply reject requests made with a User-Agent header that does not make it look like the request came from a “regular” browser … so I’d try faking one of those first. (Of course it could be a multitude of other reasons as well. Sites using popular DDoS protections services such as Cloudfront might be a tougher challenge.)

Comment: Your code is working fine at my end. Can you please share the screenshot?

Comment: @swaroopDeval Screenshot added

Comment: why there is @ in front of $html?

Comment: as @04FS said, this website is not accepting this kind of requests. That is why it gave "403 Forbidden" (means you dont have permission to access the file).

Comment: But if I paste the link in a facebook post, the image and other info appears. There must be a way to get this data.

Comment: Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: @04FS Sorry but I dont know how to do what you sugested. Anyway I'm using chrome.

Comment: Try setting a User-Agent for PHP to use with such requests. http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.user-agent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the way.

I added:

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        "http" => array(
        "header" => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
        )
    )
);
$sites_html = file_get_contents('https://andresmartin.org/2016/09/mindfulness-la-fibromialgia-mirar-dolor-amabilidad-alivia-malestar-reduce-dolor/', false, $context);
```

Now it works fine.